# Blog Posts as Files Instead of Folders?

Tags: posts

Currently, wordpress displays my blog posts as `http://example.com/blog-post-here/` but what i want is instead is to have my posts as php files instead of folders like this: `http://example.com/blog-post-here.php`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Hi Joe Bobby. You have already asked 40 questions and certainly read [ask], right? Please file an [edit] and show us. Thanks!

Comment: Joe Bobby, please … Questions like yours get closed as being "too broad" or "unclear what you are asking" and you know that. Show your research, show what you tried, show where you failed – and by that I do not mean a missing "is" in a sentence.

Comment: @kaiser i have searched sir and i just dont see anything, i have tried google searchin this site, and i dont see anything regarding using php files as folders for my blog posts

Comment: Do you want to move away from WordPress or do you just want a different Url structure? If so, search for "rewrite API".

Comment: @JoeBobby searching for .php files as folders will get you nowhere on the Internet. It's like searching for "tires that taste like bubblegum", or "dick picks that are not on the Internet". That doesn't exist (maybe bubblegum tires do exist!). Honestly your question is really not one that makes sense man. No one here wants to be an asshole, but when questions like this pop up, what did you expect? "I want x is to be is y like is y here. How?" Seriously? Put some effort bro, otherwise you will be treated as a spammer.

Comment: The question is pretty obvious. I am not sure what was so unclear? Anyways, I do not recommend to add file extensions on urls. But if you want to do it there is a [right google query](https://www.google.com/search?q=adding+php+extension+to+wordpress+post+url).

Comment: marking as "too broad" as this is basically just a more complex variant of making a static site out of a wordpress site..

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Permalinks and set your permalink structure to `/%postname%.php`. Simples.